# AlethZero and MIX IDE Deploy Dapps

Tags: ethereum

I am starting in Dapps development, I prefer use AlethZero and MIX IDE because I need in short time develop a Dapp for my article.

I mining in AlethZero and so, I have ether in my private chain. I already deploy a test scenario, but I still do not understand how I will to put the scenario deployed in the TEST NET on ethereum.

Answer (score 0):

Deploying to the public testnet (a.k.a. [Morden](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/721/87)) works exactly the same way. All you need to do is to run AlethZero on testnet:

```
alethzero --morden
```

If mining does not work for you for some reason, you can get testnet Ether from a [faucet here](http://faucet.ma.cx:3000/).

Note, that AlethZero and Mix IDE are not further being developed and if you run into trouble you will most likely get any help. For future reference, you should look into:

- [Truffle](https://github.com/ConsenSys/truffle), a development environment, testing framework and asset pipeline
- [Embark](https://iurimatias.github.io/embark-framework/), a framework that allows you to easily develop and deploy DApps
- [Browser solidity](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/) for smart contract debugging.

as possible replacements.

Comment: I got mine on testnet with mist, is so easy. I already started in truffle with testrcp, and I got deploy my contract of the MIX-IDE to testrpc. But, I have a dout about the Truffle, how I can put my build in the testnet?